# My 4.3 month old Persian cat passed away suddenly

Tags: cats, health, heart-health

My kitten was doing well till yesterday evening. But suddenly she started facing breathing difficulty at 07:30 PM in the evening. I called the Vet and told him symptoms which were no running nose and eyes, breathing rapidly and lethargy.

As per Vet suggestion we provided water and kept her in open area for half an hour. But still there was no improvement so we took the kitten to Vet. After reaching there she became totally non responsive (no movement in body and also stopped blinking eyes) which almost sound like she is gone. But our Vet gave it few injections and started drip following which my kitten came back to sense and started responding.

As per Vet, her heartbeat was increased and reason was not clear what caused it. We got her back home by 11:00 PM and she was calm for around 30 minutes after which she again started showing the signs of same discomfort. I again called my Vet but as per him we already did everything possible and now only option is to monitor her behaviour during night and bring back early morning for checkup.

She was continuously meowing without voice (her voice was low since the day she was with us) with increasing restlessness and by 01:30 AM she was breathing slowly and body movement was negligible and finally went to sleep at 02:30 AM.

I am not able to understand what went wrong. Though she is gone but still I want to know what was the cause behind this sudden difficulties my kitten has to go through?

Comment: I hope someone can answer your question, but please be aware that we are no vets. The one person who knows most about what happened to your cat is the vet that treated her. It's almost impossible to diagnose such a severe medical problem without actually physically examining the cat.

Answer (score 2):

This is such a sad story. You loved your kitten and did everything you could to help her. You "spared no expense," as they say. You say:

> I am not able to understand what went wrong. Though she is gone but
>   still I want to know what was the cause behind this sudden
>   difficulties my kitten has to go through?

I understand. I'm sure you realize that no one on the internet can diagnose your beloved cat posthumously, but what you need is support and compassion through this terrible time. If you are like I was when my dog suddenly got sick last summer and had to be put down, you are in shock.

My dog was old. She had been part of my life for nearly ten years. She had been an adult when I got her from the shelter, about five years old, so she was fourteen last summer. All those years I had structured my schedule, my life, around caring for my dog. When she got sick, I took her to the vet. When she had to go out in the middle of the night, I got up, got dressed, and took her out. She was old but seemed in good health until one day she started throwing up. Then came the pain. By the next morning I knew that short of some  miracle medicine she had to be put down. I had no choice. But for a long time I was in shock.

I really wanted to know what went wrong. Before putting her down the vet did a blood test and x-ray but nothing showed up. I would have loved to have an autopsy but that cost too much. I understand your need to know what went wrong. I think that is normal in a time like this. We want to know if there would have been something we could have done--we just want to know why our beloved pet died. Maybe we think it might ease the pain. Probably it wouldn't but in our pain we can't think very rationally.

At the time, I didn't want to think about getting another pet. But a few months later I did get a cat. That finally eased the pain. I still miss my dog but having another animal to dote on and love and care for fills the empty spot. I'm sorry I can't give a better answer to your question but I do understand why you are asking. Maybe that is enough.